# comma separate number keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a comma separated number as I keep typing the number, the comma should be inserted at appropriate places

`1234 -> 1,234`
`12345->12,345`
`123456->123,456`

I tried this logic, if the length is 4, insert the `,`. But if i have 5 digit number, this logic doesn't hold.

```
<input type="text" id="num" />


$('#num').on('keydown', function() {
   if(jQuery(this).val().length % 4 == 0) {
    jQuery(this).val((jQuery(this).val()).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
   }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q499a1z0/2/)

**UPDATE**

```
$('#num').on('keyup', function() {
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().split(',').join(''));
    jQuery(this).val((jQuery(this).val()).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q499a1z0/3/)

Comment: Normally it is better to it when user blurs the input since changing the value can cause user's cursor to jump around.

Comment: You need to remove the comma and that code has a bug in it. You have the one ) at the wrong spot. And the %3 logic needs to be changed.

Comment: working, missed the logic to remove the comma